Button within Select list that makes a POST call to add a new item to the list Primevue
I have a Primevue Select dropdown list that retrieves the items from the datatable. I want to add a button to that same list that makes a post call to add another item to the datatable. Have no idea how to achieve this. Here is the code:
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: "AddWine",
    props: {
        wineTypes: Array,
        countries: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {            
            visible: false,
            selected: {
            name:'',
            wine_type: '',
            country: ''
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addWine() {
            this.visible = false
            axios.post("http://localhost:8081/wine", this.selected)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)  
             })
            .catch((error) => {
                window.alert(`The API returned an error: ${error}`);
            })
        },
        addCountry() {
            axios.post("http://localhost:8081/country", this.selected)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)  
             })
            .catch((error) => {
                window.alert(`The API returned an error: ${error}`);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="card flex justify-center">
        <Button label="+ Add Wine" @click="visible = true" />
        <Dialog v-model:visible="visible" modal header="What wine would you like to add?" :style="{ width: '25rem' }">
            <div class="flex items-center gap-4 mb-4">
                <label for="name" class="font-semibold w-24">Name</label>
                <InputText v-model="selected.name" id="name" class="w-full md:w-[14rem]" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-4 mb-4">
                <label for="wineTypes" class="font-semibold w-24">Type</label>
                <Select v-model="selected.wine_type" :options="wineTypes" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" class="w-full md:w-[14rem]" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-4 mb-8">
                <label for="countries" class="font-semibold w-24">Country</label>
                <Select v-model="selected.country" :options="countries" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" class="w-full md:w-[14rem]" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-end gap-2">
                <Button type="button" label="Cancel" severity="secondary" @click="visible = false"/>
                <Button type="button" label="Save" @click="addWine" />
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    </div> 
</template>

I tried adding a button as a template or an option but no luck, the button is no displayed.

Please be more specific.  There are multiple selects, arrays, buttons, etc. in your code but your description is extremely vague about which specifically you're talking about.  Is it a problem with the "Save" button? It's the only thing I see with any kind of "add" functionality, but I don't see any reason why it would not render.  You should provide minimal, reproducible example.  Here's a stackblitz with your code to maybe get you started
